# Homodyne and heterodyne detection for light statistics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, experimental-physics, quantum-optics, quantum-measurements

I'm learning about homodyne and heterodyne detection in quantum optics, but I'm having some trouble understanding how these two detection schemes are used in practice to measure the statistics of your light. My question is:
Why can you measure the Wigner function through balanced homodyne detection (how would you do this in practice) and why can you measure the Q-representation of light through heterodyne detection (again how would you do this in practice and what would such a measurement scheme look like)? I have gone through the books by Scully & Zubairy as well as Walls and Milburn, but I can't seem to find a good explanation.